# Bower install doesn't run "install" step

Tags: javascript, bower

Can't seem to find anyone with the exact same issue so I'll pop it here.

Essentially I'm trying to install a package (found here: https://github.com/Chrisui/constructor/) however it never runs the install step (copying from cache to bower_components folder) as far as I can see from the output despite downloading the correct archive and extracting it into the cache fine.

Every other package I've tried has installed fine so guessing I've done something wrong with registering/creating the package?

You can see the output here:

```
$ bower install constructor#0.1.0
bower not-cached    git://github.com/Chrisui/constructor.git#0.1.0
bower resolve       git://github.com/Chrisui/constructor.git#0.1.0
bower download      https://github.com/Chrisui/constructor/archive/
bower extract       constructor#0.1.0 archive.tar.gz
bower resolved      git://github.com/Chrisui/constructor.git#0.1.0
```

Running windows
Node v0.10.20
Bower v1.2.7
Git v1.8.4.msysgit.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forked your project and tried a install with bower. Same problem.

Then I renamed your package in bower.json from constructor to foo and tagged it 0.1.1. Now it works fine.

I guess bower chokes on the constructor name. Not sure why, as it is not a reserved word, but that was what I suspected. You should open an issue in the bower project.

It should at least notify that something failed and during what step. Now it just silently fails.